# The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'FlowdioContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views

Tags: entity-framework-5

This is the error screen.
At the time of migration this exception is occurring.
What is going wrong?

> The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'FlowdioContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click the .edmx file from your visual studio;
2. Point to item "Entity Framework" in the menu;
3. Select "Generate Views".

The views will be regenerated and you will be fine after that.

Comment: Which plugin do you use for this, because I don't see "Entity Framework" on right click. Using VS2015 Enterprise btw.

Comment: @Ytrog You need to use Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2010 and also you need to install Entity Framework Power Tools. Then command will be available, see below link for details.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj593170(v=vs.113).aspx